# Exit process value in C

Tags: c, unix, signals, fork

In this piece of code I receive some commands, convert them to an array and execute them in a process.

My question is how can I make a process that takes more than exec_timeout secs to terminate?

Any help?

```
void exec_Task(int exec_timeout, char *args, int n){
signal(SIGALRM, handler);
int i=0;
int j=0;
int len;
int pa;

int flag;
pid_t p;
int fd[2];
const char s[2] = "|"; //sets the delimiter for the token
char *token;
char tasks[n][50];
wordexp_t wt;           //warning cleaner
char **w;               //wordexp related


token = strtok(args, s);    // breaks the string into smaller strings whenever the char '|' appears
                            //token gets the value of the first substring
    i =0;
    while( token != NULL )      // walk through other tokens
    {
        strcpy(tasks[i],token); // inserts them in an 2D array
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }

    for(i=0; i<(sizeof(tasks[0])-2); i++) //cleans the first task since it has the command char appanded
        tasks[0][i]=tasks[0][i+2];

    for(i=0;i<n ;i++){                  //Number of commands to execute
        pipe(fd);
        p=fork();                       //Creates child process

        wordexp(tasks[i], &wt, 0);
        w = wt.we_wordv;

        if(p==0){
            if(i<n-1){
                close(fd[0]);
                dup2(fd[1],1);
            }
            dup2(pa,0);
            //executes command
            if(execvp(w[0],w)== -1){
                perror("execvp error");
            }
            _exit(1);
        }
        else{
            close(fd[1]);
            pa=fd[0];
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<n ;i ++){
        int status=0, f=0;
        printf("wifexited: %d\n",WIFEXITED(status));
        wait(&status);
            alarm(3);
            pause();
            kill(p,SIGKILL);
        }
    close(fd[1]);
    }
```

Comment: You need to wait *first*, to get the status, and *then* check whether it indicates exit.  Look into `waitpid()` if you want to check for exit without blocking.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But if I use wait it gets stuck until the process exits. So I tried and used the "WNOHANG" option (return immediately if no child has exited.) but no luck

EDIT: my WIFEXISTED returns 1 when trying one command and keeps returning 0 when I do the same again

Comment: You can't get an exit status from another process until it has died.  What are you really wanting to do?  You have an uninitialized variable `status` in your loop, and you test this value with `WIFEXITED` which is bound to lead to indeterminate behaviour.  You will need to rethink what you're up to, somehow.  You can use `kill(0, pid)` to test whether you could send a signal to the process identified by `pid`. Your code has numerous other problems too — leaking pipe file descriptors like there's no tomorrow amongst them (and not tracking child processes). You have a lot of clean up work to do.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my post, better explained I hope.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. trap `SIGCHLD` to catch chidren termination and remove the zombies with a call to `wait`, and remove the timeout if all processes terminated
2. set an alarm for the timeout and catch `SIGALRM` to `kill` remaining processes and `wait` to remove the zombies
3. `sigsuspend` or `pause` your process to make it wait for some of this events

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how can I make a process that takes more than
>   exec_timeout secs to terminate?

In the child process, `sleep(exec_timeout+1)`.